# Get a first argument when pipe operator used

Tags: elixir

Pipe operator is very nice thing.
For example, I wish to use enumerable into `Enum.reduce` or something yet:

```
foo |> bar(...) |> Enum.reduce([], fn x, acc -> acc ++ [Enum.at(<enumerable>, x)] end)
```

Then I am compelled to write:

```
enumerable = foo |> bar(...)
Enum.reduce(enumerable, [], fn x, acc -> acc ++ [Enum.at(enumerable, x)] end)
```

May be exist syntax sugar for the first argument when used pipe operator as well as `&1` in anonymous function?

Comment: I think in your second example, you forgot `enumerable` as a first argument to `Enum.reduce`. Even with that, I still not clear to me what it should do. You have something like `[3, 1, 2]` and want it transformed to `[2, 3, 1]`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot first argument. Edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a good idea to simply move the whole `Enum.reduce` to its own function that takes one argument and name it, so everyone can understand what is it doing. `rearrange` is not the most descriptive name, but I am not sure how is this procedure used in your app.

```
def rearrange(enumerable) do
  Enum.reduce(enumerable, [], fn x, acc -> acc ++ [Enum.at(enumerable, x)] end)
end

foo |> bar(...) |> rearrange
```

Another solution would be to use anonymous function as you mentioned in your question. It is worse, but I mention it for completeness.

```
&(Enum.reduce(&1, [], fn x, acc -> acc ++ [Enum.at(&1, x)] end))
```

This looks really convoluted. You have anonymous function inside anonymous function, but it shows, that you can use `&1` more than one time in your function.

Lastly, `acc ++ [thing]` is really bad idea, because it recreates the list in memory from scratch every time. It is O(n). `Enum.at` is also linear and so is `Enum.reduce`, so this function is O(n^3).

You can do `fn x, acc -> [Enum.at(enumerable, x) | acc] end` instead and reverse the result at the end.

```
def rearrange(enumerable) do
  enumerable
  |> Enum.reduce([], fn x, acc -> [Enum.at(enumerable, x) | acc] end)
  |> Enum.reverse
end
```

`[thing | acc]` is O(1). This will make the whole procedure O(n^2) and that is reasonable time for what it is doing.

Comment: I wonder, that Elixir doesn't have usual insertion operation into list. Therefore I am using ++ operator, I thought it more clearly than `[thing | list]` and reverse. It turned out to be slow... Any way, thanks!

Comment: Lists in Elixir are singly linked lists internally. It has its limitations, but works great with immutability. For example, when you have `long_list` and prepend different things: `[a | long_list]` and `[b | long_list]` internally it points to the same `long_list`, because it can't change. If you could modify the list with `[long_list] ++ [element]`, it would broke this optimization. The downside is of course that appending is slow O(n) and requires copying entire long list just to append an element.